# SQL Server String Concat with Stuff

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, concatenation

I've looked online a few days now to how to use STUFF on sql server, most of the examples I see are involving only two tables and my query is going through 3 tables and I just can't get it to work here is the query without the STUFF function which gets me all the data I want :

```
select c.category_name,r.role_name
from categories as c 
join role_categ as rc on c.category_id=rc.category_id 
join roles as r on r.role_id=rc.role_id
where rc.c_read='1';
```

[image: These are the results]

What I want is where you have a Category_name then Id want all the role_names in one cell in row one ex:

```
BCM-Télécopieur-photocopieur Admin,Administation
```

Here what I have with the stuff function but doesnt work jsut gives me the same table as the other query

```
select c.category_name,STUFF((
    select ','+r.role_name
    from roles as r
    where rc.role_id=r.role_id
    for xml path('')),1,1,'')
from role_categ as rc
join categories as c on c.category_id=rc.category_id
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `SELECT DISTINCT` to main query and change `,` to `-`

Comment: `STUFF` doesn't do any string concatenation. `FOR XML` is doing the heavy lifting here and produces a string like `,abc,def,ghi`. All that `STUFF` does is remove that leading comma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a version of what I came up with. @GiorgosBetsos was correct that the `JOIN` needs to be moved to the inner query. I'm not sure why he's still seeing duplicates, but the following query returns the data as expected:

```
-- Set up the data
DECLARE @roles TABLE (role_id INT, role_name VARCHAR(20))
DECLARE @role_categories TABLE (category_id INT, role_id INT)
DECLARE @categories TABLE (category_id INT, category_name VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @roles (role_id, role_name) VALUES (1, 'Admin'), (2, 'Administration'), (3, 'Tech')
INSERT INTO @categories (category_id, category_name) VALUES (1, 'Consultant'), (2, 'FTP'), (3, 'Logicals')
INSERT INTO @role_categories (category_id, role_id) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1)

-- The query
SELECT
    C.category_name,
    STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + R.role_name
        FROM
            @role_categories RC
        INNER JOIN @roles R ON R.role_id = RC.role_id
        WHERE
            RC.category_id = C.category_id AND
            RC.c_read = 1
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM
    @categories C
```

Comment: The main query doesn't do a `JOIN` to `role_categ`, so you get no duplicates. There is an additional predicate `c_read = '1'` in the query mentioned in the OP though, so I guess you also have to join to `role_categ`.

Comment: I've added the `c_read` to the inner query. I was going off of the last statement in the question, so I missed that part. It still works with no duplicates. You still only need `role_categ` once in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c_out.category_name,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + r.role_name
              FROM roles as r
              INNER JOIN role_categ as rc ON rc.role_id=r.role_id
              WHERE rc_out.category_id=rc.category_id
              FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM role_categ AS rc_out
JOIN categories AS c_out ON c_out.category_id = rc_out.category_id
WHERE rc_out.c_read = '1'
```

You need to `JOIN` to `role_categ` table inside the subquery, so that you can correlate to `category_id`. Also, you have to use `DISTINCT` in the outer query in order to filter out duplicate records.

Comment: I think that you can do away with the `DISTINCT` if you only have the `JOIN` in the inner query.

Comment: @TomH I have tested the query with sample data of my own and it returns duplicates without the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Not sure what the deal is then, as I've run both my own version and a modified version of your query without `DISTINCT` with no issues. I'll post it below as an answer and maybe you'll spot something that I've missed.

Comment: Perfect this work and the explanation was awesome I actually understadn where I was going wrong thanks, but some of the results have tech where they shouldnt have they all have admin,tehc, adminitation, where only three of them should have tech

Comment: @therrienri Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Hello it is now possible to concatenate string in group by with SQL Server, by using STRING_AGG function.
Here an example

--- Create table

```
create table test_string_agg(
id int,
str_text varchar(100)
)
```

-- Insert

```
insert into test_string_agg 
values (1,'Text1'),(1,'Text2'),(1,'Text3'), (2,'Text4')
```

--Request

```
select id, STRING_AGG(str_text, ';') as t_string_agg from test_string_agg
group by id
```

--Result

```
-------------------------------
|  id     | t_string_agg
----------------------------------
|   1     | Text1;Text2;Text3
---------------------------------
|   2     | Text4
-----------------------------------
```